# Flutter Web: Access development server from another device

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using Flutter Web and want to setup the development server for multiple devices.
I'm currently running the server like this:

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 5000
```

This works for http://localhost:5000 but when I try to access the server from http://127.0.0.1:5000/ even on the same machine it doesn't work.

How can make the server accessible from any device under the same network **without** building the app?

Answer (score 1):

#### NEW ANSWER

[Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com) should enable you to make a tunnel to your localhost.

On linux you can:

1. [Install Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/installation)
2. Create a tunnel which point to localhost:5000 with `cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:5000/`
3. Use the given address to access your local development website from anywhere

Note that this is still slow. I would say it's good enough if you need to check on other devices once in a while but not if you want to develop like you would with hot reload.

#### OLD ANSWER (This seem to be really slow for an unknown reason)

You should look into something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

On linux you can:

1. Install ngrok: `sudo apt install ngrok`
2. Create a tunnel which point to localhost:5000 with `ngrok http 5000`
3. Use the given address to access your local development website from anywhere

Comment: Ngrok works but seems to take too long to load. Took 1.5mins to load a single text in flutter.

Comment: Indeed it's slow for me too, using the --region flag might help. For example if you are in the eu: ngrok http -region=eu 5050. Don't get your hopes up though, I've having trouble on my end

Comment: I already used the --region flag as eu since I'm inside the eu but its still slow for me.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you receive a notification upon response modification so I'm telling you here: I recently tried `cloudflare` instead of `ngrok` and it seems to work well enough to be usable. Not perfect but usable at least.

Comment: The question was asking how to configure the server to accept connections over a local network. ngrok/Cloudflare create a tunnel to allow the server to be accessed over the Internet, while this does work it's not an efficient way of doing it, I'll add an answer if I find a way to do it properly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `--web-hostname 0.0.0.0`;

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 5000
```

This tells it to listen on all addresses.

Answer (score 1):

For me hostname 0.0.0.0 does not work (it works with PHP but not for Flutter)

flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 5000

It works when using actual local IP number of my machine

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by running flutter on chrome (`flutter run -d Chrome`) and then pointing ngrok to the port exposed by flutter (check out the url in your chrome browser on your computer).